# filter a json array of objects with same ID and given condition

Tags: java, arrays, json

> Given a Json Array like this:

```
[{"TID":"12P","APP":"V"}, {"TID":"12P","APP":"S"},
{"TID":"12P","APP":"V_xz"}, {"TID":"12P","APP":"V_tvc"},
{"TID":"78L","APP":"V"}, {"TID":"78L","APP":"V_tvc"},
{"TID":"7MP","APP":"S"}, {"TID":"7MP","APP":"V_tvc"},
{"TID":"5P","APP":"V_xv"}, {"TID":"5P","APP":"V_cd"}]
```

> The final output of the above Json Array should be:

```
[{"TID":"12P","APP":"V"},
{"TID":"78L","APP":"V"},
{"TID":"7MP","APP":"S"}]
```

For every record with SAME TID, I have to check if objects:

1. have APP as both "V" and "S" present then only objects with APP="V" should be fetched
2. have APP as "V" and not as "S", then objects with APP="V" should be fetched
3. have APP as "S" and not as "V", then objects with APP="S" should be fetched
4. have APP as value other than "V" and "S" should be ignored

Comment: Please, share your attempt to solve this ... excercise?

Answer (score 0):

The solution may vary depending on the used implementation of `JsonArray`, but general approach includes the following tasks:

1. read the input JSON string into `JsonArray`
2. iterate the input array, filter out the values containing the `"APP"` field with the values other than `"V"` or `"S"`
3. group by the `"TID"` field, resolve collision in favor of `"V"` values
4. add to the resulting `JsonArray`

If `javax.json.JsonArray` is used, the code of the solution is as follows:

```java
static JsonArray filterArray(String json) {
    JsonReader reader = Json.createReader(new StringReader(json));
    JsonArray jsonaArray = reader.readArray();

    Set<String> appValues = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("V", "S"));

    return jsonaArray.stream()
            .map(JsonObject.class::cast)
            .filter(jo -> appValues.contains(jo.getString("APP")))
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                jo -> jo.getString("TID"),
                jo -> jo,
                (v1, v2) -> Stream.of(v1, v2)
                    .sorted(Comparator.comparing((JsonObject job) -> job.getString("APP"))
                                      .reversed()
                    )
                    .findFirst().get(),
                    LinkedHashMap::new
            ))
            .values()
            .stream()
            .collect(JsonCollectors.toJsonArray());
}
```

Here [`javax.json-api`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.json/javax.json-api/1.1.4) library is used providing [`JsonCollectors`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/json/stream/JsonCollectors.html)

Test:

```java
String JSON = ...; // long JSON data
System.out.println(filterArray(JSON));
```

Output:

```java
[{"TID":"12P","APP":"V"},{"TID":"78L","APP":"V"},{"TID":"7MP","APP":"S"}]
```

---

Similar solution using Jackson library:

```java
static ArrayNode filterArrayJackson(String json) throws IOException {
    Set<String> appValues = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("V", "S"));
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    ArrayNode array = (ArrayNode) mapper.readTree(new StringReader(json));
    return StreamSupport.stream(array.spliterator(), false)
            .filter(node -> appValues.contains(node.get("APP").asText()))
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                node -> node.get("TID").asText(),
                node -> node,
                (v1, v2) -> Stream.of(v1, v2)
                    .sorted(Comparator.comparing((JsonNode job) -> job.get("APP").asText())
                                      .reversed()
                    )
                    .findFirst().get(),
                    LinkedHashMap::new
            ))
            .values()
            .stream()
            .reduce(
                mapper.createArrayNode(), 
                ArrayNode::add, 
                (acc, arr) -> {acc.addAll(arr); return acc;}
            );
}
```

Custom collector may be used instead of [`Stream::reduce`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce-U-java.util.function.BiFunction-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-):

```java
// ...
    .collect(Collector.of(
        mapper::createArrayNode, ArrayNode::add, 
        (acc, arr) -> {acc.addAll(arr); return acc;}
    ));
```